# vuejs how can force to update a vuejs var container inside javascript function (not method of vuejs)

Tags: vue.js

For example I have a var of vuejs called: `isRender` when the `onClick` function is called as a result of a click event, it also calls `doSomething` but does not render its value correctly.

How can I force to updated the isRender value correctly?

```
data() {
    return {
      isRender:'false'
    };
},
methods:{
  onClicked(){
    cons doSomething=()=>{
      this.isRender=!this.isRender;
    }
    doSomething();
  }
}
```

Comment: why you put a function inside a method

Comment: 'false' - it's a string. Is it a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

```
data() {
    return {
      isRender:false
    };
},
methods:{
  onClicked(){
    this.doSomething();
  },
  doSomething(){
    this.isRender=!this.isRender;
  }
}
```